Array Objects Around Ellipse
I want to evenly array some squares around an ellipse so that the squares are facing inwards.  I followed the thread here
How to make objects follow a ellipse? (Duplication around ellipse)
This is very close to what I want but I need the squares to be perfectly symmetrical (mine isn't quite perfectly symmetrical).  Here's a screenshot 
Is there a way to adjust the squares to be perfectly symmetrical?

So is your problem distributing the squares as your title suggests or is your problem getting a symmetrical ellipse?

I've added an answer to your linked question, because I suppose, strictly speaking, this is a duplicate, and it shouldn't be posted here .. if it works for you, let us know.

Hi.  The problem is getting an even distribution with symmetry.  Your answer on the other thread is incredibly close Robin! I just need a square to be on the top and bottom quadrants but no squares on the left or right quadrants.

@Bedson Honestly, especially the last part of your comment with squares at top and bottom but not left and right does not really come across in your question, not at all. Your question sounds as if you have a non-symmetrical ellipse and want to know how to symmetrically place squares along with it. The problem is, even with the given answer this would not give a symmetrical distribution if the ellipse was not symmetrical so I thought you were looking for a way to symmetrize the ellipse before placing squares. Anyway, since Robin seems to have understood your question correctly, nevermind.

In addition to the question linked in your post, you look for:

Evenly distributed instances, by curve-length
The constraint that the instances are located symmetrically across the major and minor axes of the ellipse
The option to set the implicit polygon of instances 'point up' or 'side up'

Geometry Nodes give you the distribution
The symmetry is provided by the natural construction of a curve ellipse: a Bezier curve-circle with 4 control-points on the axes, scaled along the axes in Edit Mode (or in Geometry Nodes, itself).
The simplest way I can think of to the 'point up' option is to double up the instances, and select every other one, with an optional offset:

With an even count of instances not divisible by 4, that means instances on one axis and gaps on the other:



Oops, I forgot to plug in the 'Rotation'.. between Curve to Points and Instance on Points  see other answer...
